# UITableView ordering nib rows

Tags: ios, json, swift, uitableview

I have the following TableViewController code for creating a table with rows:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    switch (arrayData[indexPath.row].cell) {
    case 0:

        let cell = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("FirstCell", owner: self, options: nil)?.first as! FirstCell
        if arrayData[indexPath.row].image == nil {
            cell.firstImage.image = arrayData[indexPath.row].image
        } else {
            cell.firstImage.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "pump")
        }
        cell.firstCellLabel.text = arrayData[indexPath.row].text
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear

        return cell

    case 1...98:
        let cell = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("StationPumpCell", owner: self, options: nil)?.first as! StationPumpCell
        //cell.pumpImage.image = arrayData[indexPath.row].image
        cell.pumpLabel.text = arrayData[indexPath.row].text
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear

        switch (arrayData[indexPath.row].stat) {
            case 1:
                cell.pumpImage.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "online")
            case 3:
                cell.pumpImage.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "warning")
                cell.pumpLabel.textColor = UIColor.orange
            default:
                cell.pumpImage.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "offline")
                cell.pumpLabel.textColor = UIColor.lightGray
        }

        if (arrayData[indexPath.row].map == 0) {
            cell.pumpLabel.text?.append(" - test")
        }

        return cell

    case 99:
        let cell = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("LastCell", owner: self, options: nil)?.first as! LastCell
        return cell

    default:
        let cell = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("FirstCell", owner: self, options: nil)?.first as! FirstCell
        //cell.firstImage.image = arrayData[indexPath.row].image
        //cell.firstCellLabel.text = arrayData[indexPath.row].text

        print("oops")

        return cell
    }

}
```

the array looks like this

```
cellData(cell : 0, text : self.annotationTitle, image: self.stationImage, stat: nil, map: nil)
```

The above '0' is the header and should always be first.
Following cells are numbered 1...98 and the footer is 99. Ie. the order is: header, rows of data, footer.

The problem is that sometimes the footer is at the very top, ie. ordered footer, header, data. Other times its footer, data, header. I have not yet been able to get the correct the order.

I don't know if this has anything to do with the data being collected from an online json file and some cells loading slightly later than the footer, which has no content inside.

The image for the header (cell 0) is found like this:

```
   Alamofire.request(stationsURL).responseJSON { response in

        if response.result.value != nil {
            NSLog("Success")
            let stationsJSON = JSON(response.result.value!)

            let stationResp = stationsJSON["Stations"][0]["photos"][0].stringValue

            stationPhoto = stationResp

            print(stationPhoto)

            let imageURL = "http://www.123.com/files/thumb100_" + stationPhoto

            print(imageURL)

            Alamofire.request(imageURL).responseImage { response in

                if response.result.value != nil {

                    self.stationImage = response.result.value!

                    debugPrint("Stationimage: ")
                    debugPrint(self.stationImage)

                }
            }

        }
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }
```

That debug print of Stationimage is the very last thing that loads, according to the debug window and the header cell shows no image: `"Stationimage: " <UIImage: 0x17028ffa0>, {50, 37.5}` and I think this may be what's causing the bad ordering.

```
2017-03-10 04:34:00.290406 Testfile[14214:6238055] [INFO] {}[Database]: recovered 12 frames from WAL file …Testfile/Cache.db-wal (Code 283)
2017-03-10 04:34:00.678731 Testfile[14214:6237998] Success
Demo
http://**json address**
2017-03-10 04:34:07.753937 Testfile[14214:6237998] Success
p9_2.jpg
http://**json address**/thumb100_p9_2.jpg
[Testfile.cellData(cell: 99, text: nil, image: nil, stat: nil, map: nil), 
Testfile.cellData(cell: 0, text: Demo, image: Optional(<UIImage: 0x17409d1a0>, {0, 0}), stat: nil, map: nil)]
2017-03-10 04:34:07.872660 Testfile[14214:6237998] Success
5
[Testfile.cellData(cell: 99, text: nil, image: nil, stat: nil, map: nil), 
Testfile.cellData(cell: 0, text: Demo, image: Optional(<UIImage: 0x17409d1a0>, {0, 0}), stat: nil, map: nil), 
Testfile.cellData(cell: 1, text: Name 1, image: nil, stat: 1, map: 1), 
Testfile.cellData(cell: 2, text: Name 2, image: nil, stat: 1, map: 1), 
Testfile.cellData(cell: 3, text: Name 3, image: nil, stat: 1, map: 1), 
Testfile.cellData(cell: 4, text: Name 4, image: nil, stat: 0, map: 1), 
Testfile.cellData(cell: 5, text: Name 5, image: nil, stat: 0, map: 1)]
"Stationimage: "
<UIImage: 0x17409f8b0>, {50, 37.5}
```

What is the correct way to order the cells so that 0 is always first, 99 always last?

Answer (score 0):

It is either you change that from the query in the backend (you sort the response) or by code. If you want by code, please show some code.

Comment: Thanks, Farid. I have partially solved this with `self.arrayData.sort { $0.cell < $1.cell }` and also the image is now loading. This always sorts the cells correctly, which is great, but there's another problem. Since cell 0 has the picture, it takes a few ms more to load. When the modal is opened, cells 1-99 often (not always) load faster and align to the top of the screen, then 0 loads. The quirk is that there is a slight jump on the screen when cells 1-99 make room for cell 0. Not sure how to work this out. If I put `sleep(1)` in the code, it loads well, but not a great solution.